# Question on a set X, where every finite subset of X is an element of X

Tags: set-theory

I am working through this question (attached) in preparing for an exam next week, but I haven't managed to solve the very last part d(ii). I have included the whole question since often the earlier parts of the question give a hint on how to approach the later parts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for not asking for proofs of all of this, as some other members sometimes do.:)

Comment: I get more out of it if I can do the problem myself, so I only ask if I've given the question a proper go and am still really stuck!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of the proof is, add finite subsets of a given set repeatedly so eventually we get a set with desired property. More formally, consider the following recursively defined sequence:

- $A_0 = A$ and
- $A_{n+1} = A_n \cup [A_n]^{<\omega}$

where $[B]^{<\omega}$ is a collection of all finite subsets of $B$. You can see that $\langle A_n : n<\omega\rangle$ forms an increasing sequence of sets.

Now consider $X = \bigcup_{n<\omega} A_n$, then $X$ contains $A$ as its subset. I claim that $X$ is definitive. If $Y\subseteq X$ is a finite subset, then $Y\subseteq A_n$ for some $n$ (enumerate elements of $Y$ and check where they belongs to.) Therefore $Y\in A_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think perhaps you made a small mistake in the last paragraph, shouldn't it be Y⊆An instead of Y⊆Xn, and similarly Y∈An+1?

Comment: @lkjhgfdsa Right, I made a typo :)

Comment: I've got a follow up question: It seems intuitive, but how would you go about proving formally that the set you gave above is contained in every definitive set containing X?

Comment: @lkjhgfdsa You can prove $A_n\subseteq Y$ for any definitive $Y$ containing $X$, by induction on $n$.